# PHP Warning: File upload error - unable to create a temporary file in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04, apache2

My ubuntu vps' php was uploading images fine while running php5, but after upgrading to php5.6 all websites on my vps are no longer uploading images I keep getting this error

```
PHP Warning: File upload error - unable to create a temporary file in Unknown on line 0,
```

What could be the problem and how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

There where some changes regarding the upload directory between php5 and php5.6 see the [changelogs](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php), you can do then a search for the upload term.

Here an interesting bug [#67551](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67551)

My first advice would be to verify the config of your upload directory

If it's not the issue look at the other fix regarding the upload between Php5 and 5.6

EDIT: you can also have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395163/warning-file-upload-error-unable-to-create-a-temporary-file-in-unknown-on-lin), but you should set the right properly, chmod 777 is a big security hole .